# Full text searching phone numbers

Tags: sql-server

I want to implement full-text indexes on a column, in my Azure SQL database, that contains phone numbers.

I've attempted using different parameters and wildcards in my CONTAINS predicate.

I'm not able to use a workaround I've seen, to store the column to search in reverse-string order.

The table being queried is extremely large (in addition to other search functionality we're using on the system) which is the driver of our need for this full-text index.

First here's a simplified table

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumbers (PhoneNumber NVARCHAR(100))
```

Next I store a phone number

```
INSERT INTO PhoneNumber ('491212780579')
```

Now users perform a search on the phone number field.  In this example our user searches for: 1212780579

To the database that query appears as:

```
SELECT * FROM PhoneNumber WHERE CONTAINS(PhoneNumber, '"1212780579"')
```

I expect the query to return the phone number, 491212780579, stored in the table since the search string is contained within the data entered in that column. It doesn't return at all.

Am I misusing the full-text search functionality?

Comment: Full text is meant for words, not numbers. I imagine numbers are stop words or noise words.

Comment: @HoneyBadger That's what I thought too, so I disabled the stop list on the index but sadly nothing changed :(

Comment: So after some more thinking, it looks moving back to using LIKE is the best approach for me here.  My other columns can use the FTI just fine, but for the sake of simplicity I feel reverting is my best option.